# css a tag didn't go to the right

Tags: html, css

Please enlarge the html view width to see my point.

I have used the `a` tag in for places (as you see), just in two of them the a tag goes to the right but in two of them the a tag didn't.

The ID is `DropdownSeviceLinkAvgWaitingTime` and `DropdownSeviceLinkQueuedCalls`.

I tried to give fload right but doesn't work.

I really tried hard to re produce the problem, i hope you got me. if you need any other information please tell me.

The left is correct, the right is not

[image]

Comment: could post the css class "AddWK" - I tried to find it in the fiddle but there's loads of css to search through for it

Comment: Just a hint for future questions, Marco. Make your fiddles simpler, so only show the problem. We did not need to see all that other stuff, and it makes it harder for people to search through all your code. Also, simplifying your code in the fiddle often leads to finding your problem yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector:

```
#DropdownSeviceLink, #DropdownSeviceLinkAbandon, DropdownSeviceLinkAvgWaitingTime, DropdownSeviceLinkQueuedCalls
```

is wrong. You are missing `#`s to indicate IDs.

Comment: OMG< I wish that is just the problem, I will check and update you